# How can i make my Bot show only some directories from my Commands

Tags: javascript, directory, discord.js

Hello everyone i've been trying to do a help command which lists all directories and their files. The problem is that i want to keep some of those directories/commands secretly.
How to implement this Code into Embeds i do already know so i just wanna know how to make only some directories available to see. This is what i made so far: `

let categories = [];

```
        fs.readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
            const commands = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) =>
              file.endsWith(".js")
            );
    
            const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
              let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);
    
              if (!file.name) return //"No command name.";
    
              let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");
    
              return `\`${name}\``;
            });
    
            let FileData = new Object();
    
            FileData = {
              name: dir.toUpperCase(),
              value: cmds.length === 0 ? "In progress." : cmds.join(" "),
            };

            const InvalidDirs = [
                'blaxyy-server',
                'minecraft-server',
                'owner-only'
            ]

            categories.push(FileData)
        });`
```

The commands and directory names should be then on the Embed but i want to keep the directories which are listed in InvalidDirs private so not everyone sees them.

Anybody knows how i could do it?

Comment: Try something like `if (InvalidDirs.includes(dir)) return;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each file that you want to keep secret, add a property like this

```js
name: 'command name',
description: 'Command Description.',
secret: true,
```

Then check for it here

```js
fs.readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
    const commands = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) =>
        file.endsWith(".js")
    );

    const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
        let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);

        if (file.secret) return; // this is the line that will check for the secret property

        if (!file.name) return //"No command name.";

        let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

        return `\`${name}\``;
    });

    let FileData = new Object();

    FileData = {
        name: dir.toUpperCase(),
        value: cmds.length === 0 ? "In progress." : cmds.join(" "),
    };

    categories.push(FileData)
});
```